# How to update entities in Hibernate Search

Tags: java, lucene, hibernate-search

I have just started to work on Hibernate Search. I have a question about updating of indexes. Firstly, I index my entities which have @Indexed annotation. When I change a field which is an other entity attribute, I can observe this changing on the index of updating entity. But I can't observe this changing on other indexed entities which have the changed entity attribute.

Relevant classes: Client, Company and Body

Client class:

```
@Entity
@Indexed
@Analyzer(impl = org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardAnalyzer.class)
public class Client implements Serializable {
    ...

    @IndexEmbedded(includePaths = {"name"})
    @OneToOne
    private Body body;

    ...
}
```

Company class:

```
@Entity
@Indexed
@Analyzer(impl = org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardAnalyzer.class)
public class Company implements Serializable {
    ...

    @IndexEmbedded(includePaths = {"body.name"})
    @OneToMany
    private Client client;

    ...
}
```

Body class:

```
@Entity
public class Body implements Serializable {
    ...

    @Field(index = YES, analyze = Analyze.YES, store = Store.YES)
    private String name;

    ...
}
```

I update index manually. The Code:

```
public void save(Object entity, Long id) {
    FullTextEntityManager ftem = EntityManagerUtil.getFullTextEntityManager();
    EntityManagerUtil.beginTransactionForFullText(ftem);
    entity = ftem.find(entity.getClass(), id);
    ftem.index(entity);
    ftem.flushToIndexes();
    ftem.clear();
    EntityManagerUtil.commitTransactionForFullText(ftem);
}
```

In this example, when I change the name of body in Client instance, the index of Client instance is updated correctly. I send Client instance parameter to my save method. However, if this client is an attribute of Company instance, I can not observe any changes in company index. I don't use bidirectional relationship. How can I observe all relevant changes without using bidirectional relationships in the indexes?